# What can we do about very low quality question?

Tags: discussion

I mean, most of the titles aren't even questions. Some people don't even write complete sentences. "Low quality" here is related to the amount of effort put before and during question writing. It has nothing to do with seemingly "easy" or "newbie" questions.

Should we create a rule and the appropriate flag to remove such questions or to put them on hold with an explanation?
I know there are already flags for that. But:

```
flag > should be closed > ...
```

does not give any suitable reasons.

As well:

```
flag > rude or abusive
```

is not quite right.

There should be a way to put a question on hold until the OP makes the requested changes (or prefers to delete his own question).

Comment: There has recently been a flood of horrendously-worded homework questions. Upvote.